# Why is there a term $3.70074\times 10^{-17}x^2$ in this solution?

Tags: quadratics, computational-mathematics, wolfram-alpha

I was using WolframAlpha to find a polynomial of degree up to $2$ that best fits the points $(-1,2),(0,0),(1,-2),(2,-4)$. The answer I was expecting is
$$0x^2-2x+0.$$
However, here is what [WoldframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=quadratic%20fit%20%28-1%2C2%29%2C%280%2C0%29%2C%281%2C-2%29%2C%282%2C-4%29) shows me:

[image]

I do not understand the term $3.70074\times 10^{-17}x^2$ is this problem. May I know by what algorithm does WolframAlpha get this term?

Comment: That term is $0$, just an artifact of the numerical method.  Using InterpolatingPolynomial works better, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=InterpolatingPolynomial%5B%7B%7B-1%2C2%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C-2%7D%2C%7B2%2C-4%7D%7D%2Cx%5D)

Comment: @lulu do you know what the numerical method is?

Comment: No, but it could easily just be a simple version of Newton's method or the like.  For that, you'd probably tell the machine to stop if iteration wasn't really improving matters.  That rule tends to result in these annoying pseudo-zero terms.

Comment: `Chop[Fit[{{-1,2},{0,0},{1,-2},{2,-4}}, {1, x, x^2}, x]]` might help. WolframAlpha is really Mathematica in disguise, so using Mathematica functions sometimes works better.